# Getting Error in Self hosted WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

We have WCF Service using basichttpbinding and it is hosted inside MVC application.On Testing stage,SSL certificate is enabled on MVC application site and load balancer is also there.
We are getting below error while accessing service in console app.
The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). 
If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. 
The first 932 bytes of the response were: '#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; 
MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}
P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT:
 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT:
 #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.
 heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px;
 MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{'.

Comment: <HTML><HEAD><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" 
href="*****.svc?disco"/><STYLE type="text/css">

Comment: above text was also there is error message